# how to convert a single text file to a csv

Tags: r, csv

Im trying to take in a table from a text file and then output it (or convert it) to a csv for easier manipulation. I looked and cannot find any specific help on this task.

The text file looks something like this:

```
C#             CLA OLA Quiz Exam FinalExam
c1234501    10 20 10 30 30
c1234502     9 10  5 20 20
c1234503    10 17  8 27 27
c1234504     8 14 10 29 15
c1234505     7 18  3 24 27
```

and I would like to get it to output like this:

```
C#,CLA,OLA,Quiz,Exam,FinalExam,
c1234501,10,20,10,30,30,
c1234502,9,10,5,20,20,
c1234503,10,17,8,27,27,
c1234504,8, 14, 10, 29, 15,
c1234505,7, 18,  3, 24, 27,
```

with the comma as the delimiter.
So far Ive come up with this code:

```
tab = read.delim(file, header = TRUE)
write.table(tab, file="name_file.csv",sep=",",col.names=TRUE,row.names=FALSE)
```

but the results arent what I thought they would be:

```
"C.","CLA.OLA.Quiz.Exam.FinalExam"
"c1234501","10 20 10 30 30"
"c1234502"," 9 10  5 20 20"
"c1234503","10 17  8 27 27"
"c1234504   "," 8 14 10 29 15"
"c1234505   "," 7 18  3 24 27"
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try (1) `read.table()`  instead of `read.delim()`; (2) use `quote=FALSE` with `write.csv()`

Comment: tried it, and it gives me a weird error `Error in read.table(file, header = TRUE) : more columns than column name`

Comment: also add `comment=""` in `read.table()`

Comment: that works! thanks. last thing I would have to do is add a comma to the last element of each line in the output: `C#,CLA,OLA,Quiz,Exam,FinalExam,` any idea how to do that?

Comment: ok so found that eol=",\n" will add the comma before the new line in the output. thanks for your help

Comment: @BigShiba: why do want to add a comma at the end? It will effectively give you an extra column that's completely empty. It could lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2):

In explicit terms:

```
tab <- read.table("name_file.txt", comment="", header=TRUE)
write.csv(tab, "name_file.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

I know you didn't ask for it, but if you're essentially using R as a file converter, it might be more convenient to just use `sed` or something similar through a console/terminal. F.ex:

```
sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]+/,/g' name_file.txt > name_file.csv
```